# SUM IF is taking so long

Tags: mysql, sql

I`m trying to count my query but its taking to long. My query:

```
SELECT ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
       an.bedroom, an.bathroom, an.total_area, an.useable_area,
            an.buy_price as buy_price,
            an.rental_price as rental_price,
            (
                SELECT COUNT(id) FROM announces 
                WHERE announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
                AND bedroom = an.bedroom
                AND bathroom = an.bathroom
                AND total_area = an.total_area
                AND useable_area = an.useable_area
                AND address_id = an.address_id
            ) as isConcorrente
            FROM addresses ad
            RIGHT JOIN announces an ON ad.id = an.address_id
```

Takes 0,0086 secounds to execute. I tried to first create a sub table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (
   SELECT ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
   an.bedroom, an.bathroom, an.total_area, an.useable_area,
        an.buy_price as buy_price,
        an.rental_price as rental_price,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(id) FROM announces 
            WHERE announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
            AND bedroom = an.bedroom
            AND bathroom = an.bathroom
            AND total_area = an.total_area
            AND useable_area = an.useable_area
            AND address_id = an.address_id
        ) as isConcorrente
        FROM addresses ad
        RIGHT JOIN announces an ON ad.id = an.address_id
        HAVING isConcorrente > 0
     ) t
```

Which takes infinity time to execute.

I also tried without sub table:

```
SELECT 
ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
 an.bedroom, an.bathroom, an.total_area, an.useable_area,
            an.buy_price as buy_price,
            an.rental_price as rental_price,
 SUM(CASE WHEN (
                SELECT COUNT(id) FROM announces 
                WHERE announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
                AND bedroom = an.bedroom
                AND bathroom = an.bathroom
                AND total_area = an.total_area
                AND useable_area = an.useable_area
                AND address_id = an.address_id
            ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

            FROM addresses ad
            RIGHT JOIN announces an ON ad.id = an.address_id
```

How can I do this query faster?

Im using mysql on `5.6.26`

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Are you sure you need `RIGHT JOIN`? That will return rows in `announces` that don't have a matching row in `addresses`. Is that a possible combination?

Comment: I need to return only rows in announces that have match on address. Should I use `LEFT JOIN`? But the main problem is: why my `count` is taking so long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to count the number of rows where the `isConcorrente` subquery returns a `COUNT(*)` greater than 0, i.e. where the subquery finds at least one row.

The correct way to check for "at least one row" is to use an `EXISTS` or an `IN` clause, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM announces an
 WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT *
            FROM addresses ad
           WHERE ad.id = an.address_id
       )
   AND EXISTS (
          SELECT *
            FROM announces a2
           WHERE a2.announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
             AND a2.bedroom = an.bedroom
             AND a2.bathroom = an.bathroom
             AND a2.total_area = an.total_area
             AND a2.useable_area = an.useable_area
             AND a2.address_id = an.address_id
       )
```

Comment: This is the ideia but your answers is taking so long as well. How can I make your query faster?

Comment: @TiagoCastro Make sure you have good indexes. I assume `addresses` already has an index on `id`, since that looks like the primary key. For `announces`, the optimal for query performance would be an index with all 6 columns mentioned, in any order. Such an index may be too heavy on maintenance, i.e. slows inserts, so an index on fewer columns may be a good compromise, depending on the selectivity of such a query, i.e. how many "false positives" would be found using such a partial the index. An index on `address_id` might be enough.

Comment: There is already one index on address_id. Should I create on multiple index for (announcer, bedroom, bathroom, total_area, useable_area, address_id) grouped?

Comment: Ok, What I did was to create an multiple index and use where exist which works very well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count the final result, you don't need to use `COUNT(*)` in the subquery. Just use `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id, an.id,
            an.bedroom, an.bathroom, an.total_area, an.useable_area,
            an.buy_price, an.rental_price) AS total
FROM addresses AS ad
INNER JOIN announces AS an ON ad.id = an.address_id
WHERE an.announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
```

Rows with a zero count in `announces` won't be included in the join.

To make the grouping and joining fast, both tables should have a multi-column index on `(bedroom, bathroom, total_area, usable_area, address_id)`

Comment: Its faster But I need to count this result, how can I do that without sub table ?

Comment: See my simplified answer.

Comment: The problem is that I want to count the number of rows where the isConcorrente subquery returns a COUNT(*) greater than 0

Comment: If the count is zero, there's nothing to join with, so it won't be included in this count.

Comment: The problem is that I need to check each row like @andreas did. Why I cant just do a sub table and count it? Why its take so long?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write subquery before FROM and after WHERE part.
Sometimes subquery gets executed in the loop. It totally depends on the MySQL query optimization algorithm.
in my understanding, if subquery depends on the current row of the table returned from the outer query it will be executed in the loop.

```
select 
    ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
    an.bedroom, an.bathroom, an.total_area, an.useable_area,
    an.buy_price as buy_price,
    an.rental_price as rental_price,
    mi.result
from announces an
left join addresses ad
    on ad.id = an.address_id
left join 
(
    select bedroom, 
        bathroom, 
        total_area, 
        useable_area, 
        address_id,
        count(id) as 'result'
    from announces
    where announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
    group by bedroom, bathroom, total_area, useable_area, address_id 
) mi
    on mi.bedroom = an.bedroom
    and mi.bathroom = an.bathroom
    and mi.total_area = an.total_area
    and mi.useable_area = an.useable_area;
```

if you have unique in index on announces table id column then try following query.

```
select 
ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
an.bedroom, an.bathroom, an.total_area, an.useable_area,
an.buy_price as buy_price,
an.rental_price as rental_price,
count(an2.id) as 'count'
from announces an1
left join announces an2
    on an1.bedroom = an2.bedroom
    and an1.bathroom = an2.bathroom
    and an1.total_area = an2.total_area
    and an1.useable_area = an2.address_id
    and an1.address_id = an2.address_id
    and an2.announcer = 'Manhattan Imóveis'
left join addresses ad
    on ad.id = an1.address_id
group by an1.id;
```

please change the count column name in the result.